# image not uploaded to specified folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to simply upload a image to a specified folder but cant figure out why is the controller function not working.Here is the controller code

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '400';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload()){
        echo "image uploaded";
    }

    echo $this->input->post('username');
}
```

And this is the form to input image file in view folder

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo    site_url('welcome/do_upload');?>">
username:<input type="text" name="username">
<p>upload file</p>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass file input name 'image' in do_upload function, by default its 'userfile'

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '400';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('image')){ //passed 'image' file control input name in form
        echo "image uploaded";
    }

        echo $this->input->post('username');
 }
```

Comment: the message that is to be displayed after image upload is not displayed. no error display at all